# Вывод разного контента для планшетов-телефонов и PC

Tags: wordpress

Доброго. Друзья, как в wordpress показать разный контент для пользователей PC  и планшетов/телефонов?
Такое на яве

```
<div id="aleosoftimage" style="display:none">
<img src="flashmovie.gif">
</div>

<div id="aleosoftflash" style="display:block">

<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0" width="540" height="140">
<param name="movie" value="flashmovie.swf" />
<param name="quality" value="high" />
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
<embed src="flashmovie.swf"
quality="high"
type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
WMODE="transparent"
width="540"
height="140"
pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"
allowScriptAccess="always" />
</object> 

</div>

<script language="javascript"> 
if ((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) != null) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i) != null)) { document.getElementById("aleosoftimage").style.display = "block"; document.getElementById("aleosoftflash").style.display = "none"; }
</script>
```

А хочется на php,  чтобы страница сразу открывалась с  блоком кода, под конкретное устройство

Спасибо

Comment: ну подозреваю, что тип устройства в http не передается, но думаю передается тип браузера и ось, может по ним?)

Comment: нашел решение
http://codecanyon.net/item/mobile-content-mobile-detection-wordpress-plugin/4169385

если кто в поиске, искать по запросу wordpress plugin mobile detector
Всем спасибо